# How do I make an android splash screen for flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

I have seen a lot of articles and youtube videos and tried everything however i cannot change the android splash screen color

drawable/launch_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#2196F3</color>
</resources>
```

Production Build with key output:

[image]

Comment: please share `values/styles.xml` file, problems can be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really simple to create Native splash screens using this package.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

add this package in your `dev-dependencies`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.2.9
```

add the following code in your YAML file.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"
  image: "assets/splash.png"
```

and run the command

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

That's all, This package will take care of all the process.

> FYI: This creates native splash screens for both Android and iOS, but
> you can control it too. if you want to create only for Android, you
> can set the iOS property to false. Documentation of the Package is
> pretty clear.

Comment: I don't want use package, exist other solution?